# mysql cluster node lost connection shutdown

Tags: replication, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

I'm testing a mysql cluster with VirtualBox using several virtual machines:

Each virtual machine (2 in total) has a mysqld and ndbd node. Plus there's a vm for the ndb_mgmd to manage the cluster.

I was trying out several scenarios (basically failure scenarios) and there's one that I'm not sure is a configuration error or normal behaviour.

When I suspend/pause one (and just one) of the mysqld/ndbd vm, and then resume the same vm, I get the following message in ndb_mgm:

```
Node 3: Forced node shutdown completed. Caused by error 2305: 'Node lost connection to other nodes and can not form a unpartitioned cluster, please investigate if there are errors on other nodes (arbitration error). Temporary error, restart node.
```

Node 3 is a data (ndbd) node, mysqld on the same vm works.

Data is replicated, it's only this issue that I quite can't figure out.

Is this a normal behavior when a data node loses connection to ndb_mgmd or other data nodes?

Thanks

Comment: Is this due to the split brain problem?